# There are no primary keys that match? - SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a `Resume` table like this:

[image]

And I'm running this:

```
CREATE TABLE ResumeSkill 
( 
    ResumeSkill_ID int primary key NOT NULL Identity(1,1), 
    Resume_ID int foreign key references Resume(Resume_ID), 
    Skill_ID int foreign key references Skill(skill_ID), 
    ResumeSkill_Level int NOT NULL
)
```

But SSMS throws an error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Resume' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__ResumeSki__Resum__47DBAE45'.

I'm rather confused because the names match, and while there's no data in `Resume` yet, `Resume_ID` is set as the primary key.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Post the definition of Resume.

Comment: Just because you have a table `Resume` with an int column named `Resume_ID`, it does not mean that column is set as a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your table `Resume` does not have a primary key (or unique constraint) with the column `Resume_ID`. If this is the case it won't be possible to "point" a foreign key to this table.

Maybe the column does not exist. Maybe you misspelled its name. Maybe it does actually exist, but it's not a primary key.

Bottom line: check the column exists, it has the exact name you want to use, and check there's a primary key with it (or a unique constraint).